# Reload Method of table view is not reloading

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to fetch the data from JSON. It comes for first time in table view but second time it's not reloading data.

[image]

```
-(void)textFieldChange:(UITextField *)textfield
{
    [tbl1 reloadData];
    if (textfield.text.length==2)
    {
        NSString *post = [NSString    stringWithFormat:@"domain=MyPera&key=MyPera&email=%@&password=%@&action=MyPera&term=MyPera"];

        ///// CHANGE ////////////////
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[post length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *ret = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"]];

        [ret setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        //[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [ret setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [ret setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSURLResponse *response=nil;
        NSError *error=nil;

        NSData *newData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:ret    returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        //json parse
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:newData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response :%@",responseString);

        NSData *jsonData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSError *e;
        array2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&e];
        avar=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        rec_id=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (int i=0; i<array2.count; i++)
        {
            [avar addObject:[[array2 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"value"]];
            [rec_id addObject:[[array2 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"uid"]];
        }
        //[tbl1 reloadData];
    }
    else if (txt1.text.length==1)
    {
        tbl1.dataSource=nil;
        avar=nil; //avar is mutable data....
        [tbl1 reloadData];
    }
}
```

I am using search as type functionality it works better first time but when I press backspace or remove character tableview doesn't display data. I also declare datasource and delegate of table but not working.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to release the data after all that code? Looks like you've tried bc I see its commented out

Comment: Why do you do: tbl1.dataSource = nil ?